# I need to add data from Gridview/DataTable to placeholder of a textbox in asp.net using databinding expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

nothing appers in this part of code as executed

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFname" Width="220px" placeholder='<%# Eval("FName") %>' CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

code behind File:

```
DataTable dt = blu.getUserByUserName(Session["Fname"].ToString());
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Comment: Do you sure `FName` column has datatable?

Comment: Yes Datatable does have different column, Fname is one of them.

Comment: Do you call GridView1.DataBind() anywhere?

Comment: Do you check is working as`Text=<%# Eval("FName") %>`?

Comment: @Joe No i dont want to show the gridview on the page so i didnt bind it.
I just want to use the gridview to populate the colum data to the textbox.

Eldeniz yeh i checked its not working.

Only working part is:
txtFname.Text = dt.Rows[0]["FName"].ToString();
i wanted this on placeholder not the text.